# AngularJS - delay between update a value in the scope and actual render

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an annoying problem and I cannot solve it.
The problem is that I have a **delay** (1-3 seconds) between updating any value in the scope and actual display of the value in the view (HTML).

**Controller**:

```
$scope.myVar = 'something';
```

**HTML**:

```
<span>{{myVar}}</span>
```

Once `$scope.myVar` was updated I expect the HTML to be updated immediately but it takes a few seconds. Can somebody please explain why?

Comment: Suggestion: Reduce the number of scope variables.

Answer (score 1):

Angular runs something called a **$digest cycle**. refer this [link](https://www.binpress.com/tutorial/speeding-up-angular-js-with-simple-optimizations/135)

> This cycle is an internal execution loop that runs through your entire
>   application’s bindings and checks if any values have changed. If
>   values have changed, Angular will also update any values in the Model
>   to return to a clear internal state. When we create data-bindings with
>   AngularJS, we’re creating more $$watchers and $scope Objects, which in
>   turn will take longer to process on each $digest. As we scale our
>   applications, we need to be mindful of how many scopes and bindings we
>   create, as these all add up quickly - each one being checked per
>   $digest loop.